# WordPress Write Theme Posts Not Displaying Fully

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

I'm using the WordPress Write theme (https://wordpress.org/themes/write/) and can't seem to get blog posts to display their text fully. When I preview the blog post through the WordPress dashboard it displays the entire post but this is not the case when displayed to the user. I have tested in different browsers and see the same thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When i see it from here it display the blog post proper http://demo.themegraphy.com/write/2018/03/05/standard-post-with-images/
can you share screenshot or provide me something to diagnose properly